# Bitdefender showing lot of Getting Suspicious Connection Blocked from Chrome extension Toby

Tags: antivirus, chrome, browser-extensions

I'm using GetToby Chrome extension to manage my tabs and save them for later. Lately, I've been getting lots of notifications from BitDefender about blocked suspicious attempt:

> chrome.exe attempted to establish a connection relying on an expired
>   certificate to logs.gettoby.com. We blocked the connection to keep
>   your data safe since web pages must renew their certificates with a
>   certification authority to stay current, and outdated security
>   certificates represent a risk.

This is obviously due to the expired certificate. But this made me alert as to why is Toby trying to constantly log my work, when to me it seems like it should save only what I ask it to.

Is Toby safe to use? Should I just ignore it till they renew their certificate?

Comment: http://www.gettoby.com/privacy

Comment: From that privacy policy, "[We use your information to] improve the relevance of our advertising". That's a pretty big hint.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all free apps and extensions have a trade off of privacy for free cost. Apps may log various things like your browsing history, system information, etc. and the use them to target ads for you later or to sell to other 3rd parties for profit.